# Error in Dart: The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to integrate my RASA chatbot with a flutter app. In the response section I have the following response class but get the error "The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'". I have seen that this might be because the List could be Null but I'm explicitly checking this here, so any idea why I get this error and how to resolve it?

```
class RasaResponseList {
  RasaResponseList(this.responses);

  factory RasaResponseList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
  final messages = parsedJson
    .map((dynamic i) => RasaResponse.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
    .toList();

     return RasaResponseList(messages);
   }

  final List<RasaResponse> responses;
}


class RasaResponse {
  RasaResponse(this.text, this.buttons);

  RasaResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : text = json['text'] as String,
  
    buttons = json['buttons'] != null ? ButtonList.fromJson(json['buttons']) : ButtonList([]);

  final String text;
  final ButtonList buttons;
}
```

The button class looks like this:

```
class Button {
  Button({required this.title, required this.payload});

  Button.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
  : title = json['title'] as String,
    payload = json['payload'] as String;

 String title;
 String payload;
}
```

The error message is in the line

```
"buttons = json['buttons'] != null ? ButtonList.fromJson(json['buttons']) : ButtonList([]);"
```

The class ButtonList looks like this

```
 class ButtonList {
   ButtonList(this.buttons);

   factory ButtonList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
   final messages = parsedJson
    .map((dynamic i) => Button.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
    .toList();

   return ButtonList(messages);
  }

 final List<Button> buttons;
```

Comment: What's button List?

Comment: @KaushikChandru I added the class ButtonList

Comment: Can you add a sample response that you are trying to parse please?

Comment: So I have not tried to parse something, the error is already highlighted without doing something, so the code is not running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added your codes but don't get any errors. I also tried parsing a dummy data in initState

```js
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    print(RasaResponseList(
        [RasaResponse.fromJson(json.decode('{"text":"asdf", "buttons":[]}'))]));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(children: const [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 500,
                ),
                TextField()
              ]),
            )));
  }
}

class RasaResponseList {
  RasaResponseList(this.responses);

  factory RasaResponseList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    final messages = parsedJson
        .map((dynamic i) => RasaResponse.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();

    return RasaResponseList(messages);
  }

  final List<RasaResponse> responses;
}

class RasaResponse {
  RasaResponse(this.text, this.buttons);

  RasaResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : text = json['text'] as String,
        buttons = json['buttons'] != null
            ? ButtonList.fromJson(json['buttons'])
            : ButtonList.fromJson([]);

  final String text;
  final ButtonList buttons;
}

class Button {
  Button({required this.title, required this.payload});

  Button.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : title = json['title'] as String,
        payload = json['payload'] as String;

  String title;
  String payload;
}

class ButtonList {
  ButtonList(this.buttons);

  factory ButtonList.fromJson(List<dynamic> parsedJson) {
    final messages = parsedJson
        .map((dynamic i) => Button.fromJson(i as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();

    return ButtonList(messages);
  }

  final List<Button> buttons;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for testing. Do you have any clue why I might get this error message? That I use Statelesswidget might not be the reason right?

Comment: No stateless and these classes have no connection.. Maybe a cache issue in your IDE or you added codes in wrong order. Not sure! You can use mine. :)

Comment: Actually when I use your code snippet I get again the error "The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'" at the json.decode part

Comment: what are you trying to decode? can you add that to the question please?

Comment: I meant the "decode" in your code snipped: " [RasaResponse.fromJson(json.decode('{"text":"asdf", "buttons":[]}'))]));"

Comment: I am able to run this and getting instance of RasaResponse in print